# Android listview layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have implemented listview with custom list items in my android application. What I want to achieve is that when the screen size of the device is small in width then the components/contents of the list item should move down increasing the height of the list item, similar to wrap-text in MSWord. This is not happening currently in my application. What can be done in the custom listitem layout layouts to achieve the same?

Below is my current layout of a row item of my listview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/shared_mood_item_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/default_profile_pic"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_l_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shared_mood_item_image"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/shared_mood_item_image"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linear_l_1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linear_l_1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "match_parent" as width in linear layout prams instead of wrap_content.

UPDATE

also you should use in all other view match_parent as width parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion friend. But I think I have got the problem. I haven't used different images for different screens. Smaller image made my listview look good. This is not the answer for my question but it solved my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

just define particular text size in values (dimens.xml) and create different different layouts for different different devices....  It should work for you.